# Converting grouped pandas DataFrame into 3-dimensional array for sequence prediction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've got some data which is highly structured and I am trying to convert it into a set of sequences of datapoints in order to do sequence prediction on the data using Keras. The data should be 3D array of shape `(sequence_count, max_sequence_length, feature_count)`. However, the data as stored is organized into even more levels than that.

For example, in the contrived data below, I need to create a sequence for each `UTTERANCE` in each `GAME_TURN` in each `DYAD`, with the actual features being `WORD` and `SCORE` and `SEQ_ORDINALITY` being the order each datapoint occurs in the given sequence:

```
DYAD | GAME_TURN     | UTTERANCE | SEQ_ORDINALITY | WORD     | SCORE
1    | 1             | 1         | 1              | it       | 0.48
1    | 1             | 1         | 2              | is       | 0.22
1    | 1             | 1         | 3              | yellow   | 0.81
1    | 1             | 2         | 1              | the      | 0.18
1    | 1             | 2         | 2              | big      | 0.52
1    | 1             | 2         | 3              | one      | 0.61
1    | 2             | 1         | 1              | now      | 0.45
1    | 2             | 1         | 2              | it       | 0.34
1    | 2             | 1         | 3              | is       | 0.55
1    | 2             | 1         | 4              | green    | 0.66
2    | 1             | 1         | 1              | okay     | 0.23
2    | 1             | 1         | 2              | shall    | 0.32
2    | 1             | 1         | 3              | we       | 0.43
2    | 1             | 1         | 4              | start    | 0.33
```

**How can I then get each `(word, score)` for the grouping `(dyad, game_turn, utterance)` in the most idiomatic (pandaic?) manner?** — I'm assuming there's a more elegant way to do this than by e.g. iterating over each row in each group of `(dyad, game_turn, utterance)`.

Currently, I am able to group the sequences and find the start and end datapoints, but am a loss at what to do next: My guesses would be either to use [`DataFrame.pivot(..)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`DataFrame.stack(..)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the data or to add a special "start" and "end" row marker for each group and then iteratively split the original `DataFrame` using those rows as delimiters. The logic which works is below:

```
import pandas as pd    

def read_token_sequences(infile):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile)
    utt_token_groups = df.groupby(("DYAD", "GAME_TURN", "UTTERANCE"))
    #  (sequence_count, max_sequence_length, feature_count)
    sequences = utt_token_groups.apply(create_sequence)

def create_sequence(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # TODO: create a 2D array of (sequence_length, features) 
    # with actual sequence length padded to equal max_sequence_length
    # Possibilities: "DataFrame.stack(..)" or "DataFrame.pivot(..)"?

    # Other possibility: Append a special "start sequence" row
    # with "start["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] == df["SEQ_ORDINALITY"].min() - 1"
    # and an "end sequence" row
    # with "end["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] == df["SEQ_ORDINALITY"].max() + 1"
    # Start of sequence
    first_token = df.loc[df["SEQ_ORDINALITY"].idxmin()]
    start = pd.Series(first_token, copy=True)
    start["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] = result["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] - 1
    # End of sequence
    last_token = df.loc[df["SEQ_ORDINALITY"].idxmax()]
    end = pd.Series(last_token, copy=True)
    end["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] = result["SEQ_ORDINALITY"] + 1
```

### Expected output

For the example data above, the output array might look something like this:

```
[
    [["it", 0.48], ["is", 0.22], ["yellow", 0.81]],
    [["the", 0.18], ["big", 0.52], ["one", 0.61]], 
    [["now", 0.45], ["it", 0.34], ["is", 0.55], ["green", 0.66]],
    [["okay", 0.23], ["shall", 0.32], ["we", 0.43], ["start", 0.33]]
]
```

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "pandaic". ;-)

Comment: Also, could you share your expected output?

Comment: Okay, thanks. ;) I added an expected array version of the output, but I don't absolutely need it to look exactly like that: I just need to be able to feed it into Keras input layers.

Comment: @errantlinguist is the problem resolved? I was editing another question couldn't reply to your comment

Comment: @Dark yes, your answer got me in the right direction and so I marked it; Thanks. In reality, the data is a lot more complicated than what it is here, so actually your answer doesn't work on the real data, but the `values` and `tolist()` in combination with `groupby(..)` was what was important.

Comment: Glad it helped. It hard to know where the code breaks just looking at the sample. Glad you improved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with groupby i.e

```
df['new'] = (df['SEQ_ORDINALITY'].diff() != 1).cumsum().values
```

In case you dont have a sequence then set new column to :

```
df.sort_values("SEQ_ORDINALITY", inplace=True)
sequences = df.groupby(['DYAD','GAME_TURN','UTTERANCE'])
sequences['WORD','SCORE'].apply(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).tolist()

[[['it', 0.48], ['is', 0.22], ['yellow', 0.81]],
 [['the', 0.18], ['big', 0.52], ['one', 0.61]],
 [['now', 0.45], ['it', 0.34], ['is', 0.55], ['green', 0.66]],
 [['okay', 0.23], ['shall', 0.32], ['we', 0.43], ['start', 0.33]]]
```